# Patent details changed without consent

Tags: claims

I am the inventor of a live patent application which has been altered by the owner of the patent against my wishes. If I withdraw my name from the patent application will this stop the patent going forward?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is likely nothing you can do.

An inventor has no influence over a patent application, once they have assigned away their rights.  Moreover, there is no facility for an inventor to withdraw their name, except on the grounds that they are not actually an inventor.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is not straightforward. Where was this patent application filed? Countries (and regional treaties, like the EPO or WIPO) have different rules for that.

For patents filed with the EPO, the consent of the wrongly designated person is required for corrections, except for the case where another inventor is added. The applicant must consent too, in all cases. See Guidelines for Examination, EPO, 2016, Part A, Chapter III/5.6 at
http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/guidelines/e/index.htm

I am not familiar with US rules. If you refer to a US patent application put a relevant tag to your question, maybe someone US-based will pick it up.